# Melt function error: Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names

Tags: r, melt

I need to transform this dataset where there is a column/date and a row/variable/name:

Variable 1 (%), Variable 2($):

| Name | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Value11% | Value12% | Value13% |
| Name2 | Value21% | Value22% | Value23% |
| Name3 | Value31% | Value32% | Value33% |
| Name1 | Value11$ | Value12$ | Value13$ |
| Name2 | Value21$ | Value22$ | Value23$ |
| Name3 | Value31$ | Value32$ | Value33$ |

To become a dataset where there is a column/variable and a row/date/name:

Consolidated dataset:

| Name | Date | Variable 1 | Variable 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Date 1 | Value11$. | Value11%. |
| Name1 | Date 2 | Value12$. | Value12%. |
| Name1 | Date 3 | Value13$. | Value13%. |
| Name2 | Date 1 | Value21$. | Value21%. |
| Name2 | Date 2 | Value22$. | Value22%. |
| Name2 | Date 3 | Value23$. | Value23%. |
| Name3 | Date 1 | Value31$. | Value31%. |
| Name3 | Date 2 | Value32$. | Value32%. |
| Name3 | Date 3 | Value33$. | Value33%. |

Right now, I have tried to use the first data set with the function melt with the name as id:

**melt(data, id="Name)**

Unfortunately, I have this error message: **Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
names do not match previous names**

Which can be the mistake? Are there any other options to achieve my goal?

Alternatively, I have tried to import the data from the two variables in two different datasets and have used rbind to integrate them and checck through the indetical function if the column names were the sames and the result was TRUE. I do not know which can be the reason for this error.

Thank you so much for any help folks!

Data:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Name = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3"),
            Date.1 = c("Value11%","Value21%",
                       "Value31%","Value11$","Value21$","Value31$"),
            Date.2 = c("Value12%","Value22%",
                       "Value32%","Value12$","Value22$","Value32$"),
            Date.3 = c("Value13%","Value23%",
                       "Value33%","Value13$","Value23$","Value33$")
)
```

Comment: `Variable2` in your desired output seems to be just a copy of `Variable1`, is
 that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `melt()` and `cast()` from the `reshape2` package it is
recommened to use `pivot_wider()` and `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr`
package for pivoting/reshaping between wide and long data formats.

Here is what that could look like for your data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data |>
  pivot_longer(-Name,
               names_to = "Date",
               values_to = "Variable1")
#> # A tibble: 18 × 3
#>    Name  Date   Variable1
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>    
#>  1 Name1 Date.1 Value11% 
#>  2 Name1 Date.2 Value12% 
#>  3 Name1 Date.3 Value13% 
#>  4 Name2 Date.1 Value21% 
#>  5 Name2 Date.2 Value22% 
#>  6 Name2 Date.3 Value23% 
#>  7 Name3 Date.1 Value31% 
#>  8 Name3 Date.2 Value32% 
#>  9 Name3 Date.3 Value33% 
#> 10 Name1 Date.1 Value11$ 
#> 11 Name1 Date.2 Value12$ 
#> 12 Name1 Date.3 Value13$ 
#> 13 Name2 Date.1 Value21$ 
#> 14 Name2 Date.2 Value22$ 
#> 15 Name2 Date.3 Value23$ 
#> 16 Name3 Date.1 Value31$ 
#> 17 Name3 Date.2 Value32$ 
#> 18 Name3 Date.3 Value33$
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally went for mutate() for the Date variable to convert it into date and had to transpose the variables using pivot_wider() and it worked.